# SSIS: script task (vs15) not work when deploy on sql server 2014

Tags: ssis, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-2014, vsta

The error:

> There was an exception while
>   loading Script Task from XML: System.Exception: The Script Task
>   uses version 14.0 script that is
>   not supported in this release of Integration Services. To run the
>   package, use the Script Task to create a new VSTA script. In most
>   cases, scripts are converted automatically to use a supported version,
>   when you open a SQL Server Integration Services package in
>   %SQL_PRODUCT_SHORT_NAME% Integration Services.    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.ScriptTask.LoadFromXML(XmlElement
>   elemProj, IDTSInfoEvents events)

I'm doing exactly what it says, but it does not help.

Any solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the revised version of the SSDT (now 14.0.61x), there is a fix.

1. Install new version.  ([SSDT For download](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/mt186501))
2. Right click project > Properties > Configuration Properties > General > TargetServerVersion - Update to SQL Server 2014 > Redeploy.

Comment: I Followed these steps, but again i am getting same error as above. i am using Sql server 2014 and Visual Studio version is 2015.

Answer (score 23):

This worked for me:

1. Install SSDT-BI for Visual Studio 2013.
2. Open your solution in Visual Studio 2015.
3. Select your SSIS Project in the Solution Explorer.
4. In the Project menu select Properties.
5. In the Property Pages dialog select Configuration Properties -> General
6. Under Deployment Target Version change the Target Server Version to "SQL Server 2014."
7. Clean and rebuild solution and redeploy.

Comment: This is the correct solution -- it would be unthinkable for Microsoft to permit development in Visual Studio 2015 and not support a target of SQL Server 2014.

Comment: Be sure to update SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) in VS 2015 as well -->

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=616714

Comment: I get this error with VS 2015, and a target SQL Server version of 2016 (with SQL Server 2016).

Comment: @ZachSmith - did you get a resolution? I have not found one - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47204178/deploying-ssis-package-to-sql-server-2016

Comment: In my case I just change the target server version to "SQL Server 2014", rebuild and redeploy without installing new version of Visual Studio and is working like a Charm!!

Answer (score 0):

Even though this question is a bit dated, I am getting the same error on the targeted server, but in a slightly different context:

1. created an SSIS package targeting SQL Server 2014
2. add a script task
3. deployed it to SQL Server 2014
4. package validation failed with "The Script Task uses version 15.0 script that is not supported in this release of Integration Services..."

I used the following environments for the development and deployment:

- VS2015 Update 3
- [SSDT v 17.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt)
- Deployed using [SSMS v17.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms)

The current SSDT version 17.1 provides a support to target SQL Server 2014 - SQL Server vNext.  The current version of the SSDT resolves the issue in the question by providing targeted option in the project configuration as already mentioned.

I noticed that the above SSIS project works on the targeted server if deployed with:

1. VS 2015 (Select SSIS Project -> Right Click -> Select *Deploy*)
2. SQL Server 2014 SSIS Deployment Wizard (probably available only if you have a local instance installed; found in the *Microsoft SQL Server 2014* Windows Start Menu)

If you try to deploy it using *SQL Server Management Studio v17.1* version of the *SSIS Deployment Wizard* the deployed package fails.  The deployed script task is deployed as version 15.0 that is not supported on the SQL Server 2014.

If I deploy the same package using *SSIS Deployment Wizard* from *Microsoft SQL Server vNext CTP2.0* Windows Start Menu, which probably got added by installing SSMS 17.1, the deployed package script task fails with same error.

In summary:

1. The latest [SSDT v17.1 for VS2015](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt) resolves above issue by providing targeted server configuration options
2. It needs to be deployed through Visual Studio 2015
3. It can be deployed using the targeted server version of the *SSIS Deployment Wizard*
4. If using the latest SSMS v17.1 and build-in *SSIS Deployment Wizard* the SSIS package Script Task will fail on the targeted server for being upgraded to SQL Server 2017 version

Maybe this is by design, but it is very confusing and caught me of guard.  Just in case this is a bug I submitted a [bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/3136600/ssms-17-1-integration-services-deployment-wizard-ssis-project-targeting-2014-deployed-to-sql-2014-script-task-version-deployed-as-15-0-and-fails).

Comment: hey, just wanted to chime in and mention that the error message you are getting is letting you know the version that you're building against is v15 (SQL 2018? which doesnt exist). I have seen the Package.dstx show one version even though you changed the option on the VS UI. It isn't until rebuild that the correct version gets updated. You may just need to rebuild - sometimes building isnt enough where the 'correct' version doesn't propagate throughout