# Can't Execute SSIS Package on SQL server 2016

Tags: sql-server, ssis

We have a database server with SQL server 2016 and SSIS 2016 installed on it, and another server have SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) 2015.

Then We create Ispac File from SSDT and copy it to DB server and deploy it on SSIS, when we want to Execute that package We get error shown in the picture bellow :

[image: Ssis Package Error]

We change Target version to Sql server 2016 but problem not fix.

Comment: Here's a similar error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34893267/ssis-script-task-vs15-not-work-when-deploy-on-sql-server-2014. Under the "Deployment Target Version" what is "Target Server Version". In future please copy paste the output, don't paste a picture

Comment: You need to enter your SCRIPT TASK in your ssis-package and update either references or just update its meta data. Also check your code.

Comment: I simulate My problem in my local computer and it was done!.
In Operational environment I Change Deployment Target version and it not works but it works in my local computer. I installed Data tools in My local DB server,Is It the reason of executing script task without any problem?

Comment: plaidDK I cant understand what is your mean