# SSIS package deployment on SQL Server 2016 using SSMS 2017

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2016

I am running into a problem as outlined in this artice: [Execution error while validating script component](http://sql-articles.com/articles/bi/ssis-2014-execution-error-while-validating-script-component/).  I am using Visual Studio 2015 to create SSIS packages and also upgrade old 2008 packages to be supported on SQL Server 2016.  First, Visual Studio was able to upgrade the packages and I can run them successfully from within VS2015, but not as a job on SQL Server 2016 using SSMS 2017.

The article says to use the same version of SSMS as your SQL Server and your Integration Services package version.  Is this indeed the case even with SQL Server 2016, Integration Services deployment set to 2016, and SSMS 2017?

I get the error that says the script task is corrupted.  I have tried it using deployment versions 2016 AND 2017.  Here is the error for deployment version 2017 (similar errors in 2016):

[image]

Note that I even went so far as to completely rewrite new script tasks using the same code as the old ones.  I did have to add a reference to some .NET stuff for Directory Services though.  But it compiled after I made that change.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `The article says to use the same version of SSMS as your SQL Server and your Integration Services package version` cannot confirm for SQL 2017, but this is the case with our SQL 2014 environment as of last week(we ran into the same issue upgrading 2008 packages). I would just bite the bullet and try deploying with 2016. That will most likely solve it.

Comment: Thank you, Jacob.  I'll see if we can try that out.  I appreciate your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I wasn't able to get SSMS 2016 on the server due to delay in change request but I did do a deployment from within Visual Studio to the destination server and all is well.  I found that here: [Deploying SSIS Package to SQL Server 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47204178/deploying-ssis-package-to-sql-server-2016)

I didn't install anything on my destination server though.  I just deployed from directly within Visual Studio on its server.  Some of my scripts had to be rewritten but it wasn't much of a headache.